# A more sensitive 'OnTextChange'...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am building a page where I want an update button that is hidden until such time as the user has altered some data on the page.  Therefore my first thought was to simply on my text box to add 'OnTextChanged' and then throw a Visible=true to my update button and the user would be aware they hand information on the screen that needed to be saved before they left or they would otherwise loose it.

However, OnTextChanged doesn't trigger when you start adding data to the text box nor even when you leave the text box and go to another. In fact it doesn't trigger until you do something else on the page, then it fires and my button then appears and the update can be executed by clicking on the button.

I would MUCH rather have this triggered with the first additional character space or digit is added or removed from a textbox or element rather than wait for such an event as the only thing I intend to do with these trigger points is to activate the update buttons visibility so the user can update when they are ready to.  The update routine then re-hides the button waiting for the next bit of data to change to re-light the button once again.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to do what I'm wanting to do here?  Just wanting a more sensitive OnTextChanged function.

Thanks,
Ken...

Comment: You can try onkeypress, onkeydown or onkeyup.

Comment: `OnTextChanged` is the server side event. `onchange` is the JavaScript method.

Comment: You should use Jquery's `onkeyup` event for doing this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the event `onKeyPress`. It should be triggered each time the user types a character in an input.

Here you have more [information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keypress)

Comment: Now, these suggestions are both Jquery concepts... and I was using C# in code behind to accomplish this and since this is only the textbox controls that are giving me this issue and I would prefer to maintain my method with my turning on and off of the visibly of the update button.is there a way that in Jquery I can toggle the button visibility to true?.. if so this is a perfect solution for me!

Comment: Yes, you can change this attribute through jQuery. [Here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) you have one way to accomplish this. But if you google a little bit, you'll find a few more ways to do it.

Comment: Well I thought I had this working but it turned out it didn't work! <sigh>

Comment: The only way that I could make this work is if I then had function that I could call from my code behind C# page to reset the button to invisible after making it visible... hmmm and likewise I have other controls to consider that work fine in the code behind setting that wouldn't be picked up by this that are check boxes. ... getting a headache!